# Analyzing time series

Tags: time-series

I am trying to help out a friend of mine on her assignment. As far as I understand she needs to find and analyze the trend of a time series data. Her notes are a mess so it is hard to find any material on what should I look for.

To find a trend I need to use a regression on the graph obtained and find the function expression. However, I don't understand if I should mention the function expression in the analysis. Or should I keep it at the increasing/decreasing type of description?

What else do I include in the description of the trend? Any links to notes or maybe material related to that would be appreciated. [image: the graph where I need to describe the trend or learn of the way to do so]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 9 data points per series. Time series data can have either deterministic trends (the one you are probably referring to ) or stochastic trends ... see [stochastic vs. deterministic trend in time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/461014/stochastic-vs-deterministic-trend-in-time-series)

Thus the term "trend" is ambiguous at best.

Time series analysis also allows for level shifts (intercept changes) .

Both kinds of trends can be identified with quality algorithms .

Hope this helps ...